# How to link against libGL on OSX using cmake?

Tags: opengl, cmake, linker-errors, x11, glx

I'm trying to compile [camera_calibration](https://github.com/puzzlepaint/camera_calibration) on OSX 10.11 and after a few hurdles with a few X11 related dependencies I find myself still stuck with a few linking errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glXChooseVisual", referenced from:
      vis::OpenGLContextGLX::InitializeWindowless(vis::OpenGLContextImpl*) in opengl_context_glx.cc.o
  "_glXCreateContext", referenced from:
      vis::OpenGLContextGLX::InitializeWindowless(vis::OpenGLContextImpl*) in opengl_context_glx.cc.o
  "_glXDestroyContext", referenced from:
      vis::OpenGLContextGLX::Deinitialize() in opengl_context_glx.cc.o
  "_glXGetCurrentContext", referenced from:
      vis::IsOpenGLContextAvailable() in opengl.cc.o
      vis::OpenGLContextGLX::AttachToCurrent() in opengl_context_glx.cc.o
  "_glXGetCurrentDisplay", referenced from:
      vis::OpenGLContextGLX::AttachToCurrent() in opengl_context_glx.cc.o
  "_glXGetCurrentDrawable", referenced from:
      vis::OpenGLContextGLX::AttachToCurrent() in opengl_context_glx.cc.o
  "_glXMakeCurrent", referenced from:
      vis::OpenGLContextGLX::MakeCurrent() in opengl_context_glx.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I found `libGL.dylib` has these symbols:

```
for lib in /usr/X11R6/lib/*.dylib;do nm -gU $lib | grep _glXChooseVisual;done
000000000000307f T _glXChooseVisual
000000000000307f T _glXChooseVisual
gp:src George$ for lib in /usr/X11R6/lib/*.dylib;do echo $lib && nm -gU $lib | grep _glXChooseVisual;done
/usr/X11R6/lib/libAppleWM.7.dylib
/usr/X11R6/lib/libAppleWM.dylib
/usr/X11R6/lib/libFS.6.dylib
/usr/X11R6/lib/libFS.dylib
/usr/X11R6/lib/libGL.1.dylib
000000000000307f T _glXChooseVisual
/usr/X11R6/lib/libGL.dylib
000000000000307f T _glXChooseVisual
```

However I can't seem to tweak CMakeLists.txt to take this into account.

I've tried adding:

```
set(X11R6_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/X11R6/include")
set(X11R6_LIBRARIES "/usr/X11R6/lib")
```

which I later use when calling `target_include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` for `libvis`, but doesn't seem to do the trick.

Hackily adding `-lGL` in `target_link_libraries` results in `ld: library not found for -lGL`

I've also looked at [CMake's FindOpenGL reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenGL.html) and tried using `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED COMPONENTS OpenGL GLX)` but didn't get very far:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: GLX)
```

Any tips on correctly linking against GLX via CMake on OSX ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On macOS *do not(!)* develop against X11 / GLX. *They are not natively supported!* The X11 server for macOS supports only indirect GLX with limited functionality. You will get only sub par performance. And CUDA (used by libvis) is not supported.

On macOS all OpenGL development should use the native `OpenGL` framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_contexts/opengl_contexts.html

However take note that OpenGL has been declared deprecated by Apple.

In short: You'll at least have to modify your program to use the macOS OpenGL framework, or even bite the bullet and accept that macOS is not a well supported platform for your application.

Comment: That sounds like sound advice (+1)